# How to associate an inbound Twilio call sid with custom ID?

Tags: php, rest, twilio, telephony

How to associate an inbound call sid with custom ID? Currently Twilio posts or gets its parameters to the configured voice URL, but one can't send custom parameters to twilio to callback with it's parameters. Example scanario: Caller calls in to authenticated to be connected to a different number at `/twiml.php`, Twilio posts at `/voice_url.php` at call initiation. How to then associated the current running authenticated caller with a callsid, assuming their caller id might be unknown?

- The strategy I've tried already was querying twilio for all running
  calls then matching the caller ID with the previously stored callerId
  from the twilio statuscall to the voice_url, but If i have multiple
  calls going with more than one 'unknown' caller ID, that wont work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Are you looking for a way to identify second/third time callers who have an unknown caller ID against their Twilio Call SID? This is not possible, as Call SIDs are unique to each call. Could you explain in a little more detail so I might be able to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When initiating the call, you can setup the callback url with custom parameter.

From what you explained, i understand that /voice_url.php is your callback url.
you can specify the call backurl while initiating the call as /voice_url.php?id=xxxxxxx

This will make the twilio to send the id also to your callback url, where you can fetch the id using get request parameter.

I hope this helps.

Comment: How do you set the callback url in the PHP (or Rails) app?  I do see how to set it on the Twilio website, but that is only one URL without parameters.